# как сделать чтоб AlertDialog или DialogFragment сам исчезал после задержки в 2 сек?

Tags: java, android

Программа в нужный момент показывает юзеру диалог с текстом (я использую это в качестве `popup` формы просто чтоб оповестить о событии) и нужно, чтоб эта форма задержалась на экране на 2 секунды и исчезла...

Я пробовал это сделать с помощью вызова `intent` который открывает `Activity` (которому я задаю стиль и нужные мне размеры), в этом `Activity` устанавливаю задержку и `finish()` и получается своего рода `popup`

**вот так**

```
public class PopUpActivity extends Activity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_pop_up);

    final Display display = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay();
    Point size = new Point();
    display.getSize(size);
    int screenWidth = size.x;
    int screenHeight = size.y;

    getWindow().setLayout((screenWidth * 90) / 100, (screenHeight * 40) / 100);

    Thread logoTimer = new Thread() {
        public void run() {
            try {
                int logoTimer = 0;
                while (logoTimer < 5000) {
                    sleep(100);
                    logoTimer = logoTimer + 100;
                }

                finish();

            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } finally {
                finish();
            }
        }
    };
    logoTimer.start();
}
```

Но почему то после `finish()` закрывается и это `Activity` и то из которого оно было вызвано... Не понятная причина... Мне кажется что то с потоками напутано. Поэтому я решил использовать AlertDialog или DialogFragment они нормально отбражаются, вот только осталась последняя проблема

**Как установить задержку на закрытие? чтоб оно сам вызывал `dismis()` через 2 сек**

Спасибо!

Comment: А в чем именно проблема? Вы не знаете, как выполнить какой-либо код с задержкой в 2 секунды, или как закрыть диалог?

Comment: уберите финиш либо из блока ```try{}``` либо из блока ```finally{}```, т.к. блок ```finally{}``` выполнится и при успешном завершении работы и при исключении.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
Handler handler = new Handler();
handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        //or  alertDialog.dismiss();
        //or  finish();
    }
}, 2000);
```

Comment: то что нужно. Спасибо!